# Форматирование чисел при записи в std::stringstream

Tags: c++

Выполняю следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream<<123456789<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<stream.str()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на экран:123,456,789.
Мне бы хотелось получить: 123456789

Меня интересует, как сделать, чтобы при записи числа в stream не добавлялись запятые.

Comment: Попробовал в виндозе под вижуалом 2008 и в линуксе под gcc 4.9. Никаких запятых.

Comment: Вариант с преобразованием в числовое значение( long i = atol(stream.c_str()); ) не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это эффект локализации.

Попробуйте вызвать `setlocale(LC_ALL, "C")` в начале программы (cм. [man setlocale](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setlocale)).